# How to filter using ksql with array attribute type

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a Stream on a topic with schema:

```
--root
  --name: string
  --age: integer
  --accounts: Array
    --email
```

I would like to select all root elements having accounts with email ='xx'

Thanks you for help.

Comment: Can you share an example message of the topic, exactly as it is?

Comment: Also what queries have you tried so far?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous this is an example of messages :

`{
  "NAME": "CONDA..SA.2",
  "STATION": "AMNE",
  "CATEGORY": [
    {
      "PROFILECATALOG": "HT",
      "TECHNICALDESIGNATION": "CS - Commande A",
      "CATEGORY": "CS",
      "FAMILY": "HT"
    },
    {
      "PROFILECATALOG": "HT",
      "TECHNICALDESIGNATION": "S - B",
      "CATEGORY": "S",
      "FAMILY": "HT"
    }
  ],
  "MATERIALS": []
}`

Comment: I would to select all elemnt having category  CS in the Category array

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from t1 where accounts->email='xx'
```

Assumption table or stream name is t1.

Comment: thanks you, but this work for me only if accounts is an object. in my case, accounts is an array of objects :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this

`where array_length( filter(accounts, a => (a->email = 'xxx@xxx.xx') )) >=1`

Answer (score 0):

In general case a new stream with exploded array elements must be created

```
create stream ExplodedStream
with(kafka_topic='ExplodedTopic')
as
select
  root->name,
  root->age,
  explode(root->accounts) as account
from OriginStream
```

This stream will explode one message with multiple accounts into multiple messages with one account inside. Messages will be stored in a new ExplodedTopic topic. In your case streams and topics names will be other. This topic messages can be easily filtered as

```
select * 
from ExplodedStream 
where account->email='xx'
```

If number of accounts are known then filtering can be done without creating a new stream. Just filter by all known account elements

```
select * 
from OriginStream 
where 
  root->accounts[1]->email='xx'
  or root->accounts[2]->email='xx'
  ...
  or root->accounts[n]->email='xx'
```

Number of array element is one based (1,2,3,...)

Answer (score 0):

if your events look like:

```
{
    root: {
       accounts: [
          email1,
          email2
       ]
   }
}
```

use:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root->accounts, 'email_string_to_look_for');
```

EDIT:
in case your array items are objects this use:

```
    {
        root: {
           accounts: [
              {email: email1},
              {email: email2}
           ]
       }
    }
```

use transform to convert the array of objects to array of values that you are looking for, then use array_contains function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(transform(root->accounts, (x) => x->`email`), 'email_string_to_look_for');
```

More info here:
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#array_contains